# jQuery append not working(adding css to head)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to add a stylesheet to the head of a page, but for some reason it doesn't work. Should i use something else, instead of append?

the code

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" class="test" />');
```

maybe some usefull info, i am using firefox 3.6.17

Comment: if you are adding html, use $('head').html("<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" class="test" />"); - http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: This should work - are you wrapping it in $(function(){}); ?

Comment: No, using html will remove all other code inside the head.

Comment: @John No, that will replace the content of `head`. @user759235 Your code seems to work to me.

Comment: its used inside an plugin, but i have tried it on several places, with no result

Comment: Well it worked for me - are you not seeing the styles in question applied or something?

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
loadcss = document.createElement('link');
loadcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
loadcss.setAttribute("href", "test.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
jQuery(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" class="test" />');
```

Comment: I don't believe `document.head` is supported cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should put that code in the document ready, in order to have the DOM loaded. Are you?
And then something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("head").append("<link>");
  css = $("head").children(":last");
  css.attr({
    rel:  "stylesheet",
    type: "text/css",
    href: "test.css"
  });
});
```

Comment: this works, but i use my code inside a plugin, so this dont work, or can i use an document ready inside a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("head").append("<link>");
    var css = $("head").children(":last");
    css.attr({
      rel:  "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: "test.css"
    });

});
```

example is on: http://jsfiddle.net/XjAu4/